# Footer cms block not recognized as separate block (not with template hints and Lesti FPC)

Tags: blocks, template, cache

when placing cms block in our website footer like thi with the code below. We see that the block id 'shopper_footer_links' is not picked up as a separate block. (when testing with template hints + Add add Block Names to Hints it is not shown). The only block name we see is html_footer (and not the blocks that reside within it).

I am asking  because we use LEsti FPC and do not want to cache shopper_footer_links. But if it is not recognized as a block it cannot be cached/not-cached separately.

**question:** is there an easy way so Magento does see it as a separate block id? Or does this involve writing an extension (adding the html to something like footer_after)?

Many thanks, Sean

I tried these two methods. Same outcome.

```
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('shopper_footer_links'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shopper_footer_links'); ?>
```

and in layout xml

```
    <reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="shopper_footer_links" after="shopper_footer_links">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>shopper_footer_links</block_id></action>
    </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: why do you calling your block twice in phtml file ? also I can see you didn't set `as` attribute for your block. add `as="shopper_footer_links"` for your block,then clear the cache and then load the page again

Comment: The two calls were just to show that i tried both methods (will clarify). I will add the AS and see if it works

Comment: Like this?   <block type="cms/block" name="shopper_footer_partners" as="shopper_footer_partners" after="shopper_footer_links">
   <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>shopper_footer_partners</block_id></action>
  </block>

Comment: tested. no still does not work. Also I can see in template/block hints that it is not recognized as a block

Comment: yes.. that is it

Comment: where you calling thosing blocks? in which phtml file ?

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shopper_footer_partners'); ?> this is the correct way to call your block in phtml file. phtml file means it is the template file for footer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18246/discussion-between-snh-nl-and-programmer-rkt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to fix it

both action and parameter name_in_layout seem necessary

```
    <reference name="footer">

    <block type="cms/block" name="shopper_footer_partners" name_in_layout="shopper_footer_partners">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>shopper_footer_partners</block_id></action>
        <action method="setNameInLayout"><name_in_layout>shopper_footer_partners</name_in_layout></action>
    </block>
    </reference>
```